# Function called indefinitely on property binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I discovered very strange problem in my Angular application.

Let's say I have a simple `example.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
    styles: [``]
})
export class ExampleComponent{
    get buttonShouldBeDisabled(){
        console.log("property call");
        return true;
    }
}
```

with template defined as follows

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="buttonShouldBeDisabled">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in my browsers console I can see, that string "property call" is being logged indefinitely.
[image: Indefinite property call]

What could possibly cause such behaviour? Do I understand correctly, that this means, that my property is being called over and over again and it can lead to browser not responding to user actions?

Comment: If you use function in property or attribute binding, it will be called on each change detection cycle.

Comment: Well, technically I do, since getter is a function, isn't it? Does this mean that use cases similar to my example should be handled differently? I mean I shouldn't use property nor function, but something else? If so, than what is correct approach here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Sure, using function for property or attribute binding is slightly discouraged, but it is okay if it is just one or two functions, you won't notice any decreases in performance. If I were you, I would simply use boolean variable and bind it to `disabled` attribute and I'd then change its state to true/false depending if button should be disabled or enabled.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your overall approach is fine, I would modify it like this

```
export class ExampleComponent{
isValid: boolean;

buttonShouldBeDisabled(){
    console.log("property call");
   return this.isValid;}}
```

With your html element bound to isValid

```
<button [disabled]="!buttonShouldBeDisabled>Button</button>
```

Now you can simply set the boolean for example on click of another button to toggle 'disabled'
Hope this helps, greetings from Berlin.

Answer (score 0):

i too have notice this thing in Angular. Its not an issue its something related to Angular way of detecting changes for each component.